# Send data from UWP app to Unity3D on the same machine

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, uwp, data-sharing

I have a universal apps getting data from Microsoft's Band 2 (accelerometer) and want to export the processed data in the app to the unity project to be used as input control. The data will be frequent, so real-time response is preferred.

What should I learn or use to achieve this?

Comment: If you only want to create a game that is controlled by the band then I think Nika Kasradze's answer is the way to go. However if you want to leverage other capabilities of the UWP (e.g Cortana) or have more not game related screens in your app, then you should create an app that has a "game page" and add to it. Unity will create the basic project for you if you build for UWP. (At least it did for WIndows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it would be easier to write a plugin for Unity to connect to Band directly rather than to connect to an app that connects to Band (actually I have no clue how to do that).

Having that in mind, you probably should:

1. download the [appropriate Band SDK from the official website](https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK)
2. Read about writing plugins for Unity for the platform you need ([Desktop/WP](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html), [Android](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html), [iOS](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html))
3. Draw a pentagram and hope for the best